# How use group complement in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for something like `r"[^\1]"` in Python.
For example, I want to match words like *"hello"* in a text where every letter has been replaced by one other (ex: "*a*" by "*z*", "*b*" by "*r*", ...). "hello" can be *"zcuuj"*, *"prvva"*, ... I want to say to Python: "find me a word which begins with `[a-z]`, then a letter which is **not** like the first, then the same two letters, then a letter wich is different of the others.

I've tried this pattern:

```
r"([a-z])([^\1])([^\1\2]){2}([^\1\2\3])"
```

(doesn't work)

This one:

```
r"([a-z])((?!\1))((?!\1|\2)){2}((?!\1|\2|\3])"
```

(doesn't work)

Comment: What doesn't work? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try this here

```
^([a-z])(?!\1)([a-z])(?!(?:\1|\2))(([a-z])\4)(?!(?:\1|\2|\4))[a-z]
```

I tested it online [here on rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/1GZeEFtqpv)

The problem with your second example is, the negative lookahead assertion are non consuming. That means you need to consum the characters after you checked them. I do this here after every lookahead with the `.` and the references.

The problem with your first example is, that you cant put those references in character groups.

**UPDATE**: I updated my regex and the rubular link, because the first version would have allowed other characters than `[a-z]` after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) you can use `(?P<name>...)` to create a named group that you can later reference using `(?P=name)`.